# Is this nibbana or god?

Tags: nirvana, god

There is, bhikkhus, a not-born, a not-brought-to-being, a not-made, a not-conditioned. If, bhikkhus, there were no not-born, not-brought-to-being, not-made, not-conditioned, no escape would be discerned from what is born, brought-to-being, made, conditioned. But since there is a not-born, a not-brought-to-being, a not-made, a not-conditioned, therefore an escape is discerned from what is born, brought-to-being, made, conditioned. (Sutta pitaka , khuddaka nikaya , udana 8:3)

Answer (score 4):

That is *Nibbana*, and not god or Brahman or any kind of Ultimate Reality. It is that which is experienced by the mind, when it is completely free of all fetters and defilements.

I quote from [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31737/471) below. Please see that answer for details.

> So, *Nibbana* is not a thought of the mind, not a concept of the mind,
>   not a state of the mind, not a state of consciousness and also not a
>   feeling. However, when the mind experiences this *Nibbana*, which is not
>   conditioned, not compounded, not suffering, not impermanent, not
>   arising, not ceasing and not changing, it experiences bliss. The mind
>   can therefore experience *Nibbana*, but it cannot feel it or think about
>   it.
>
> Sukha or *happiness* for an unenlightened person is experienced when
>   encountering pleasant feelings (from the six senses) or when
>   encountering the cessation of painful feelings (from the six senses).
>   But for an *arahat*, *sukha* or bliss (in this context) is experienced
>   when encountering neutral feelings, no feelings and *Nibbana*.

Comment: Does mind even still exist during nibbana ?

Comment: @user646989 Mind exists during and after Nibbana, but it is free from defilements. If you read [this sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an01/an01.049.than.html), it says "Luminous is the mind. And it is defiled by incoming defilements." The mind is however completely calm and silenced in higher jhanas. Also, see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/17926/471) for examples of thoughts entering the Buddha's mind.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar, Maimonides of the Hebrew faith also ended up saying that God could only be described through negation, and the Hindus say Brahman is 'neti neti' - 'not this, not that'.

However the difference between nibbana and God is that God is Ultimate Reality, which is where the term differes from nibbana.

If God is seen as a '1' to the '0' of our daily experience, then nibbana is the '0' to the '-1' of our daily experience. It is perhaps more melancholy, but it is less contrived, as no 'thing' needs to be pulled out of a hat.

Comment: What do you mean by ultimate reality ? The atma in Hinduism is unborn too

Comment: Just really the last paragraph. Actually, I would say not '0', but '[ ]' - an empty set for nibbana, if being pedantic. Atman however, is an attempt to build a '1' into things. That thing, existing independent of individual experience. nibbana does not exist, it does not not exist, it is not conditioned, by any thing.

Comment: No. God you're talking about is a personification of nature. Also logics or Boolean logic or set theory doesn't have anything to do here. Misleading answer.

Answer (score 1):

God, is not neccesary. Buddha didnt said, it exist, doesnt, both or neighther. 
Birth is the origination of dependant phenomenon.
Its like Electric field is always present with magnetic disc around it. Magnetic disc can be called as dependent origination, as it attract the Iron. Iron can be term as 5 khandas and when one attain nibbana, it cease to that magnetic disc. Know for sure, that magnetic disc never ceases, it always accompanied by electric field. Magnetic field can be term as anatta.
You are asking about electric field, the source of life. If you see above statements, then question of electric field is not neccessary.
Real question likes in how to attain cessation!

Comment: What's khandas ? Is there any similar concept of khanda in Hindu or Islam ? ,Is the electric field god ?

Comment: 5 Khanda mean complex of 5 elements with feeling, sensation, perception, counciousness to form being. In hinduism khanda is synonymous with Brahman. Veda stumbled into it as they term it as Supreme one, but an error. Although impermanent, they call it permanent. They cling to it. They not crossed to other shore, but remain tied to this end. Why? They didn't surrendered! To the eightfold path, a pool of coolness and purity. Electric field cannot be call by any name. It's not Worthy. It's not produce will to detachment. It's only called as place of cessation of all sufferings!

Comment: what do you think about Islam then ? Your religion is very different from them

Comment: I belong to no religion. Nor here any wish to change others. Buddhism is not religion, it's way of pure life lived here and now. There is history religion changes over time from one to another, replacing with one belief to another. I don't have any belief. I don't think only Buddhism teaches the truth, others not.

Comment: can you reconcile both Islam and Buddhism ? Do you find similarity between them ?

Comment: If you like islam then I will quote the similarity of conduct of a individual, not believer or non-believer in God. It's like this, "If one know the Mighty lord is watching over you, knows what you do, would you kill, steal, utter lie, misbehave, give false witness, talk rude and commit misdeeds? If one knows he is watching, wise man even give his body on this ear for the suffering of others and live a pure life!"  It's not belief matters, but the conduct of individual. It's not question of God, it's question of your deeds! This is reconciliation indeed!

Comment: Thanks for your love 

Answer (score 1):

There is no god, creator of all. Nibbana is the cessation of the manifested, cessation of perception of the manifested, and cessation of the memory of the manifested. Nothing remains of mind as you know it. Nibbana is unborn. It creates nothing. The question is, how does manifestation come into being?